# vscode-go, fill struct command not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i have gopls installed, and `fill struct` command is working perfectly in sublime.
but not in vscode. it ask me to install other tool, which i shouldn't need to.
fill struct is listed in `gopls api-json` command.
also, why it ask me to run `go vet` instead of `go install` command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved by upgrading to latest version.
this post is old. now, probably no one has this problem.